# Get geospatial coordinates a path projected with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have successfully project an SVG world map and some other shapes onto a sphere using D3.js.

I can easily map points to the sphere, but I don't yet have the other way around. From a mouse event, I'd like to derive the lat/lng or just the general angles at the pointer.

Before I go down the math rabbit hole, is there something built into D3.js to handle the inverted mapping? Or an existing solution otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using this library, you could try the [invert()](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_invert) method

For newer versions, as of v6 at least:

```
//in click or other mouse event handler
const coords = projection.invert(d3.pointer(event, this));
```